# Javascript $window is not defined when adding paralax scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently building a time line based page with the different years, as this is a single page with a lot of info, I decided to go with the paralax scrolling effects available, to construct my page to work in the following manner:

[image]

I have added paralax scrolling based on [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/) tutorial. But it does not function the way I want to.

I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/9CgFt/1/) to try and demonstrate what I want it to do.

I use the same JS as in the tutorial:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function () {
            var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

                // Put together our final background position
                var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';

                // Move the background
                $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
            });
        });
    });
```

But keep on getting the following message when scrolling through the page: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $window is not defined** Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

correct the `$window` to `$(window)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function () {
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        // Use the cached window object here
        $window.scroll(function () {

            // Use the cached window object here
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

            // Your code here
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9CgFt/4/)

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a new variable outside the .scroll

```
...
var $window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function () {
...
```

(beacause you use the `$window` variable inside the .scroll)